# Error to fill table from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to fill my table `SQL` from `PHP` but the result always is 0.
My table do not take account the update from my tow `files xslx`

My code is the following:

```
public function save(\...\Parse\Article $article, \Floose\\LRU $lru){
    $IdLRU=$lru->getId();
    $LRU=$lru->getLRU();
    $designation=$article->getDesigniation();
    $articleid= $article->getId();
    if ($LRU == "Unspecified") {
        $IdLRU = 40;
    } 

    else{
                if ($LRU != 'new'){
                    $check= $this->_db->query("SELECT `ID_LRU` FROM `lru` WHERE `LRU` ='".$LRU."'");
                    return true;
                }

                else if ($check->rowCount() == 0) {
                    $this->_db->query("INSERT INTO `lru` (`ID_LRU`, `LRU`) VALUES ('".$IdLRU."', '".$LRU."');");
                    $requete2 =$this->_db->query("SELECT `ID_LRU` FROM `lru` WHERE `LRU` ='".$LRU."'");
                    while($data = $requete2->fetch())
                    {
                    $IdLRU=$data['ID_LRU'];
                    }

                }
                else{
                    while($data = $check->fetch())
                    {
                    $IdLRU=$data['ID_LRU'];
                    }
                }
    }
The structure of my table is:

(ID_LRU, LRU) --> (int auto_increment, varchar)
```

Can you tell me, the problem is in my request ?

Comment: There seems to be various problems with your code - where `$check` is set there is a */ on the end of the line.  The `if ($check->rowCount() == 0) {` doesn't seem to have a close } in the right place.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it. I did edit, it's above. But he doesn't work, however I changed the NULL by a value of getId

Comment: If the above code reflects your changes, the bit which runs `$check...` will not be done before `else if ($check->rowCount() == 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

Per your post your `ID_LRU` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, means probably it's a *primary key* column. With that your below query is wrong and should through error since you are trying to insert `null` in a key column

```
_db->query("INSERT INTO `lru` (`ID_LRU`, `LRU`) VALUES (NULL,
```

Comment: Putting null into an auto-increment field just assigns the next value.

Comment: @NigelRen, answer doesn't points that ... read it carefully .. point is primary key if any

Comment: Yes ID_LRU is primary key in my table, just I should affect it the value 40 when the contition "unspecified"

Comment: @Rahul I changed NULL by the value getId() but it dosen't work,